# R Shiny -- I am unable to retrieve the selected output value from my selectInput action

Tags: r, select, shiny

I cannot seem to retrieve the selected output value from my selectInput action.
The lists from the vectors choices and selected are appropriately inserted into the UI, but the `input$Site_User_Override` variable value is always `NULL`.

```
output$Site_Pick_User = renderUI({
    choices=as.list(Subset_List()$to_Select)
    selected = Site_Pick_Initial()
    selectInput("Site_User_Override", "Override Site_Pick:", choices=choices,
        selected=selected, multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
    })
```

My single row vector `Site_Pick_Initial()="Name5_1.9mi_S"`
And the structure of `Subset_List()` is the heading and five rows below.

```
Name    STATE   lat lon Air_Miles   Bearing Rose    Rank    to_Select   Delta_Dir
Name1   NJ  42.3    -74 8.826   12.092  NNE 33  Name1_8.8mi_NNE 175.89
Name2   NJ  42.2    -74 2.690   14.615  NNE 27  Name2_2.7mi_NNE 173.37
Name3   NJ  42.3    -74 9.049   348.271 NNW 34  Name3_9.0mi_NNW 160.29
Name4   NJ  42.2    -74 3.962   329.387 NNW 28  Name4_4.0mi_NNW 141.40
Name5   NJ  42.2    -74 1.868   187.983 S   21  Name5_1.9mi_S   0.00
```

How can I retrieve the value of `input$Site_User_Override`? The code above is simplified; I need to use `input$Site_User_Override` in latter calculations and displays.

Comment: You should provide a full reproducible example and be more specific in what you want. It is too broad.

Comment: Sorry -- I know that this is only a small snippet of a much larger code block, it it is not enough to run on its own. My question is simple. From the UI, the selectInput seems to be working, but I was expecting that it would be setting a value to a variable input$Site_User_Override, or possibly setting a value to a reactive input$Site_User_Override() . I only see NULLs. How can I reference the input that I select with inputSelect?

Comment: You have to use updateSelectInput.  https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html

Comment: Thanks, Harlan Nelson -- I'll try working with updateSelectInput . Hopefully, I'll see some improvement after I incorporate updateSelectInput and work through the syntax.

Comment: And thanks, Paul, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1751961/paul for the formatting edit changes. The question is far more readable now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, the following code should be equivalent but it works totally fine. Please update if what you are trying to do is different.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("test"),
  verbatimTextOutput("debug")
)

data <- data.frame(
  Name = c("n1", "n2", "n3"), 
  to_Select = c("Name1_8.8mi_NNE", "Name4_4.0mi_NNW", "Name5_1.9mi_S"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "Site_User_Override",
      "Override Site_Pick:",
      choices = data$to_Select,
      selected = "Name5_1.9mi_S"
    )
  })

  # input$Site_User_Override is updated and can be used elsewhere
  output$debug <- renderPrint({
    input$Site_User_Override
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, Keqiang Li.
Sorry that I was so tardy replying to your prompt response.
Your fix worked perfectly, and got me over a major hurdle in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Harlan. https://stackoverflow.com/users/4629916/harlan-nelson
You gave me the lead that I needed. 
The “secret sauce” was using BOTH
selectInput() on the ui side

```
            selectInput(
                inputId = "Site1_Override",
                label = "Override Site_Pick:",
                choices = "",
                selected = ""
                )
```

AND updateSelectInput() on the server side, with an observeEvent()

```
    observeEvent(
        input$checkGroup, {
        updateSelectInput(session,
            inputId = "Site1_Override",
            label = "Override Site_Pick:",
            choices = as.list(Subset_List()$to_Select),
            selected = Site_Pick_Initial()
            )
        })
```

I saw an additional hint to the solution on a YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXh01HFyH68 where I first saw BOTH ui and server edits.

I can now successfully output the selected item,

```
    output$result_item  <- renderPrint({
        input$Site1_Override
        })
```

and

```
    output$result <- DT::renderDataTable( 
        Subset_List()[Subset_List()$to_Select  %in% input$Site1_Override,]
        )
```