# In R Shiny is a change in the value() of a reactive, an “event” for the purpose of observeEvent()

Tags: r, shiny, observers, reactive

In R Shiny, is a change in the reactive `value()` or an assignment of a reactive `value()` an "event" for the use in `observeEvent()`? I have a difficult situation where I think I need to assign priorities to all of my reactives, because of run-away flushing. I am trying to solve by inserting observers, with different priorities to control to reactive update order.

```
observeEvent(
    "value()", priority=15, {
        Widget_Avail <<- reactive ({
        ...
```

With `observeEvent(event, priority=n, {`, I see that priorities can be integers, decimals and even negative numbers. Is there any substantial difference in action, if the priority is negative? My challenge is rooted in using `updateSelectInput()` in the server, paired with `selectInput()` in the UI.

Comment: I am still working the same problem that I "closed" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836235/r-shiny-i-am-unable-to-retrieve-the-selected-output-value-from-my-selectinput

Comment: Instead of imposing side-effect on a reactive variable within an `observe` chunk, why don't you put that assignment within the `reactive` block that originally defines/controls `Widget_Avail`?

Comment: Reading of a reactive value is a reactive dependence while the assignment is not. Also, I really feel it should not be the case to redefine a reactive inside an observer. Your question is very unclear and I think you should at least give an concrete and reproducible example.

Comment: I have resolved this issue with a work-around.
`updateSelectInput()` got me most of the way but I needed multiple instances, and the reactivity brought my program into freeze territory.
The answer was simple select `selectInput()` with reactive functions for the "selected" and "allowed" values. Then the, to get the updated `selectInput()` value available to later calculations, I used a separate select button, and the new values were pushed into my calculations.